# Hide process name from system process listing

Tags: c, process, exec, fork

I am trying to launch a process from within my code , 
Initially i tried system() function call, .As i came to know that with exec  , the process overlays itself with the binary of executable being invoked then i tried exec() function .

and since first argument(argv[0]) is name of the program , i deliberately passed "datafile" as second parameter . While execution , i check processes in process listing (via ps -e / top ) , the actual name instead of "datafile" process shows in process listing !! Is there any way to hide/rename the name of the binary launched from child process ?

```
void main()
{

pid_t pid;
int status;
fflush(stdout);
pid=fork();
if(pid<0)
        exit(3);
  if(pid==0)
  {
    execlp("/usr/bin/top","datafile",NULL); // "datafile" for deceiving the ps -e
   //system(top);
  }
  else
  {
    waitpid(pid,&status,0);
    printf("\nHello %d ",pid);
    fflush(stdout);
    exit(0);
  } 
}
```

When the binary is executed the output is:

```
Swap:  3998716 total,   165756 used,  3832960 free.   379712 cached Mem

      PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                             
     3217 user      20   0  196840  12844   8120 S   0.7  0.8   0:09.02 unity-panel-ser                                               
     3650 user      20   0  320844  11976   7984 S   0.7  0.7   0:03.25 nm-applet                                                     
     7774 user      20   0    5524   1324    936 R   0.7  0.1   0:00.04 top                                                           
      630 message+  20   0    5440   2016   1028 S   0.3  0.1   0:05.06 dbus-daemon                                                   
      705 root      20   0   54864   4496   3572 S   0.3  0.3   0:05.11 NetworkManager                                                
     1025 mysql     20   0  326740  10380   1240 S   0.3  0.6   0:14.92 mysqld                                                        
     1129 root      20   0  200856  60132  46616 S   0.3  3.7   5:26.94 Xorg
```

> Hello **7774**

Here "top command" launched from mycode is visible in process listing!
My Aim here is that other users (including root) should not know what command i am firing, though multiple instances of a.out in process listing are okay!i.e. i am expecting output like:

```
7774 user      20   0  196840  12844   8120 S   0.7  0.8   0:09.02 ./a.out                                               
7773 user      20   0  320844  11976   7984 S   0.7  0.7   0:09.01 ./a.out
```

Any hint / Help will be very fruitful.

**UPDATE:**
Tried execv:

```
void main()
{

pid_t pid;
int status;
char *newargv[3] = { "neverkillme","www.yahoo.com", NULL };
fflush(stdout);
pid=fork();
if(pid<0)    exit(3);
if(pid==0)
 execv("/usr/bin/opera",newargv);
else
{
waitpid(pid,&status,0);
printf("\nneverkillme(opera) process's ID %d ",pid);
fflush(stdout);
exit(0);
}
}
```

OUTPUT: once i run a.out opera open yahoo.com under a new tab; but i can see "opera" listed as a process using ps -e

```
Initially:
ac@ac:~/Documents/C$ ps -e| grep a.out  
ac@ac:~/Documents/C$ ps -e| grep opera 
ac@ac:~/Documents/C$ ./a.out  
    ** (opera:5248): CRITICAL **: os_bar_hide: assertion 'OS_IS_BAR (bar)' failed (opera:5248): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_hide: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
    ** (opera:5248): CRITICAL **: os_bar_set_parent: assertion 'OS_IS_BAR (bar)' failed
    ** (opera:5248): CRITICAL **: os_bar_hide: assertion 'OS_IS_BAR (bar)' failed (opera:5248): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_hide: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
    ** (opera:5248): CRITICAL **: os_bar_set_parent: assertion 'OS_IS_BAR (bar)' failed
    ** (opera:5248): CRITICAL **: os_bar_hide: assertion 'OS_IS_BAR (bar)' failed (opera:5248): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_hide: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
    ** (opera:5248): CRITICAL **: os_bar_set_parent: assertion 'OS_IS_BAR (bar)' failed
    ** (opera:5248): CRITICAL **: os_bar_hide: assertion 'OS_IS_BAR (bar)' failed (opera:5248): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_hide: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
    ** (opera:5248): CRITICAL **: os_bar_set_parent: assertion 'OS_IS_BAR (bar)' failed
    ** (opera:5248): CRITICAL **: os_bar_hide: assertion 'OS_IS_BAR (bar)' failed (opera:5248): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_hide: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
    ** (opera:5248): CRITICAL **: os_bar_set_parent: assertion 'OS_IS_BAR (bar)' failed

  neverkillme(opera) process's ID 5248 

ac@ac:~/Documents/C$ ps -e| grep opera  
5248 pts/24   00:00:01 opera 
cdac@cdac-Lenovo-B590:~/Documents/C$ ps -e| grep a.out  
5247  pts/24   00:00:00 a.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure who you're trying to mess with here ;-), but the answer to your question is to use execv().  The first argument is the path of the executable to actually run, and the second argument is the argv[] array that program will receive. If you change its argv[0], your value will show up in top/ps instead of the real program name.  For example:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *newargv[4] = { "hi mom!", "-d", "60", NULL };

    execv("/usr/bin/top", newargv);
}
```

and you can check it:

```
$ ps ax | grep mom
26564 pts/10   S+     0:00 hi mom! -d 60
26573 pts/9    S+     0:00 grep mom
```

Comment: Can you explain in what way it is not working? It certainly works for me on a Red Hat Linux box.

Comment: Opera probably sets its own argv[0], or starts a subprocess with the actual name. If this is the case, there is nothing you can do about it. But try it with a simpler command like 'top' and you should see that the basic technique works.